# How to create an indexed integer colset in CPN-Tools?

Tags: petri-net, cpn-tools

How to create an indexed, easily iterable, int Colset?

I need to pass ints by index to a transition function, and I'm thinking about something with an index such as

```
colset PH = index ph with 1..n
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? It would be helpful to others on the site, if you posted your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have an example of how to use the index with a function in the following [manual](http://cpntools.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/manual.pdf) (Page 8)

Look at the declared `Chopsticks` function:

```
val n = 5;
colset PH = index ph with 1..n;
colset CS = index cs with 1..n;
var p: PH;
fun Chopsticks(ph(i)) =
1`cs(i) ++ 1`cs(if i=n then 1 else i+1);
```

When you declare an index, you declare an `id` such as `ph` or `cs`. You can pass an index by its integer value using the `id` followed by its number, like `cs(1)`.

So, if you want to iterate, you can use the integer value assigned to its id.